# Index must be within the bounds of the list - windows forms app

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, textbox, int

i am trying to take input from two textboxes to create two strings of integers to be added together. I keep getting an error that basically just says "Index must be within the bounds of the list"
here is my code

```
private char[] array1;
private char[] array2;

String input1 = tbUserInput1.Text;
        array1 = input1.ToCharArray();
        int[] op1 = new int[array1.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            op1[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array1[i].ToString());
        }

        String input2 = tbUserInput1.Text;
        array2 = input2.ToCharArray();
        int[] op2 = new int[array2.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++)
        {
            op2[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array2[i].ToString());
        }

        MessageBox.Show(Binary.AddBinary(op1, op2).ToString());
```

I have fixed the problem, it ended up being an exception that was getting thrown by my Binary class. There is one more problem I am having though. When I display my results, they are all on new lines. Obviously from my code you can see that it will create a new line everytime but is there another way to do this so its all on one line with spaces in between? heres how my new code is set up for the output

```
string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Binary.AddBinary(op1, op2));
MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Note that arrays, exception, textbox and int tags do not add any value here.

Comment: I am trying to take input from two textboxes and put the input into two arrays, the arrays will be added together by clicking a button, this will then display the result of the arrays being added together in a messagebox

Comment: `String input2 = tbUserInput1.Text;` . It should probably be `tbUserInput2`instead

Comment: nope, wasn't the fix but thank you for pointing that out as that will be important later!

Comment: Your code seems ok to me. What's `Binary.AddBinary`? In what line is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It was a very simple fix, I just needed to change

```
string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Binary.AddBinary(op1, op2));
```

to

```
string toDisplay = string.Join(" ", Binary.AddBinary(op1, op2));
```

Thank you all for your suggestions!